# Adding category filter to loaded product collection?

Tags: magento2, product-collection

**Magento 2.3.3**

This is my code:

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$values = [66];
$conditionType = "in";
$_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter([$conditionType => $values]);
```

I am trying to add a category filter to the collection, but it does not work. Any ideas why?

Thanks

**Solution looks like this:**

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear();
$values = "66";
$conditionType = "in";
$_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter([$conditionType => $values])->load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use array. Just string would be fine

like this:

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear();
$values = "66";
$conditionType = "in";
$_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter([$conditionType => $values]);
```

You can also send multiple IDs like this:

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear();
$values = "66,67,68";
$conditionType = "in";
$_productCollection->addCategoriesFilter([$conditionType => $values]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt work, still getting all products ... maybe I have to reload the collection somehow? This is on `list.phtml`.

Comment: YES, that made it work, Ill update my question with the solution.

Comment: Great, good to hear that :)